# I need to know how to use quotation marks within a list

Tags: quotations, lists

How do I punctuate this?

She said, "How many are there?", "What is his name?", and "When can she get there?"

Comment: In my opinion, this should be avoided entirely. But to answer your question, I'd do the following: _She asked, "How many are there," "What is his name," and "When can she get there?"_ By opening with _She asked,_ you eliminate the need for the first two question marks.

Comment: I might use semicolons instead of commas.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to this will depend on whether you want UK or US English punctuation conventions.  US style can be seen in an example from *Chicago Manual of Style* 6.123, where the comma is omitted following an exclamation point:

> Her favorite songs are "Hello Dolly!" "Chicago," and "Come with Me!"

Following that, yours would read:

> She said, "How many are there?" "What is his name?" and "When can she get there?"

A cleaner alternative might be the following, though it indicates that the speaker says the word "and":

> She said, "How many are there? What is his name? And when can she get there?"

UK style would put the commas after each quote:

> She said, "How many are there?", "What is his name?", and "When can she get there?"

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use semicolons, which correctly go outside quotes:

> She said, "How many are there?"; "What is his name?"; and "When can she get there?"